# Email & Web Hosting in 2 different servers

Tags: email, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting, mail-server

Not sure, if SO is the correct forum to ask hosting related questions, but i have seen a bunch of questions on SO related to hosting hence asking my question.

I have a website www.abc.com hosted on a windows server. I am having some issues with the email client of the server. Many times, either the email doesn't go properly and some users complain of receiving emails very late.  I would like to get the email issue resolved. I think I have the following options -

1. Move the hosting and email to a different server - I have tried doing that but no luck with my email issues.
2. Rewrite the code in PhP and host it on Linux server - This is because the email server on linux never gave us any issues like we're facing in Windows server.
3. Purchase an email hosting plan to the old LINUX server and keep the web hosting on the current windows server - I want to know if this option is at all feasible and is there any way I can make this work?

Please let me know if there are any other ways to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also want to know if it is possible to have emails in one type of server and the web page in another type of server. Both need to have the same domain name. Any news?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Exchange email server for your emails? From mu humble experience so far, Linux is way better for emails and web hosting.
So you may want to rewrite your code and host it on a Linux server.

Comment: No, I am using Webmail provided by the hosting provider and looking for options.